# How can I programmatically configure Windows cmd.exe settings?

Tags: windows, scripting, settings, cmd

I have a lot of different servers that I connect to.  Each time I connect to a new machine I go through the several mouse clicks to setup basic options for cmd.exe, such as QuickEdit mode and expanding the screen display and buffers.  This article describes what I do pretty well (with my own settings, of course):  http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/commandpromptoptions.mspx?mfr=true

This is annoying.  I would like  to run a quick configureCmd.cmd script upon login that will update all of these settings automatically such that when I open the cmd.exe it is already configured without any additional work on my part.  Running the script on login is easy, but I do not know where these settings are stored.  I figured the Registry, but my experiments do not show any difference in `HKLM | HKCU \Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console Windows are not part of the command processor, so it follows that their settings are separate. Take a look at 
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`.